# How I load a 2048x2048 image on Android 2.3?

Tags: android

This may sound very specific... And it kinda is.

I really need to load a 2048x2048 32-bit image on Android 2.3 (specially Nexus One and Xperia Play, where the app in its current form crashes outright with a out of memory error).

Android 2.2 loads it fine, and all androids after 2.3 load it fine too, and some 2.3 devices (usually with huge heaps) also load it fine.

The Xperia Play in particular reports (via OpenGL) that it can load images up to 4096x4096, and using Marmalade SDK I really could load crazy huge images, and many of them, easily using 150mb of memory.

But I cannot figure how to load a 2048x2048 image with Java on that device, it just throws me this error:

05-07 17:41:25.202: E/GraphicsJNI(27847): VM won't let us allocate 30965760 bytes

EDIT: Stop telling me to use lower resolution, I will quote myself:

> I really need to load a 2048x2048 32-bit image on Android 2.3

A lower sample image is not 2048x2048, neither is a higher one, or a scaled one, or a mipmap version, or anything else... I NEED TO LOAD THOSE IMAGES THE WAY THEY ARE, PERIOD.

Comment: Can you lower the image quality (supposing it's a jpg) so that it doesn't take so much memory?

Comment: It is a png, and the 30mb of memory it eats when uncompressed. (compressed it is 500kb)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

Since you don't want to scale down the image, which is understandable, you may want to look into reducing the quality/sizeInMbs of the image you are loading to memory.

For instance, you stated you have an image of 2048*2048 which is taking approximately 30 mb, that is pretty big for an image that size.

Take a look into this [demo from Romain Guy](https://code.google.com/p/xlarge-demos/source/browse/#svn/trunk/PhotoAlbum/res/drawable-nodpi) where he's using images that are 1280*752 and yet are only a few hundred kbs in size. Despite of this small size, the images look really clear and crisp on the [working demo](http://www.curious-creature.org/2011/02/18/android-3-0-animations-demo/).

---

First of all, loading a 2048*2048 image into a small device screen such as those devices you mentioned is a waste of resources. Here's a link to a [fully detailed tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) on how to scale and load large images efficiently.

Keep in mind that you should try to scale images down when possible, Android Developer site mentions that: *"An image with a higher resolution does not provide any visible benefit, but still takes up precious memory and incurs additional performance overhead due to additional on the fly scaling."*

Step one, get the image dimens first, by using BitmapFactory.Options:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

Step two, figure out a sampling factor: *How much to scale the image down*

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
// Raw height and width of image
final int height = options.outHeight;
final int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

    // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
    final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
    final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

    // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
    // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
    // requested height and width.
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
}

return inSampleSize;
}
```

Finally you can scale it down using:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
    int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

// First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

// Calculate inSampleSize
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

// Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}
```

Comment: The image actually is a image atlas for a animation, I do use its entire resolution, in fact the end result (the frames) are already showing with half of the resolution, if I used the device proper resolution, I would need 4096x4096 on Xperia Play, and 8192x8192 on tablets...

Answer (score 1):

*30965760* bytes sounds pretty big for a resolution of 2048x2048.

Could it be that the image is 32-bit per channel instead of 8-bit per channel? A common mistake when I am asking people for a 32-bit PNG is that they select the 32bit/channel (128-bit image) mode in a program such as Photoshop.

Red (**8-bit**) + Green (**8-bit**) + Blue (**8-bit**) + Alpha (**8-bit**) = a **32-bit** image.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look using BitmapRegionDecoder to load in only the portions of the bitmap which would be visible (or will be visible soon) at any given time. See: [Using BitmapRegionDecoder to load large images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11494551/using-bitmapregiondecoder-to-load-large-images)

Answer (score -1):

You will have to scale down your bitmap to reduce memory consumption.
I advice you to look at the official documentation about this matter of [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

As an extra advice, do not forget to recycle all of your unsed bitmaps. This will help GC to free that memory faster.

Answer (score -1):

If you need the full resolution for whatever reason (as opposed to the reduced resolution in daniel_c05's answer) and you can't use OpenGL (why not? it's perfect for this),

1. Split it into tiles
2. Only load and render a few tiles at a time
3. If you need efficient zooming, pre-scale the image (mipmap) and tile each level.

But really, you should be using OpenGL if you're working at that scale and want speed.

Comment: OpenGL can load directly from the apk somehow? Skipping the heap?

Comment: Yes and no. You can load assets from the apk the same way you can load them into a Bitmap. That said, you can't use the same type of compressing, so you're usually stuck with uncompressed assets or using your own png library. The real split happens because 1) those images never hit Java land uncompressed and 2) they can be offloaded to the GPU and don't even need to take up any RAM. 

If you're doing anything like this, do use a good 3D library. I heartily recommend libgdx.

Comment: I do not really understood... How you load a png file directly into OpenGL and skip the heap?